# WebVR: Origin Trial Token disables controls?

Tags: javascript, three.js, webvr

This has baffled me for quite some time. Whenever I have the latest Trial Token for WebVR active on my domain, the Three.js VRControls drag to rotate feature on desktop becomes disabled in Chrome. As soon as I remove it, the rotation works fine again.

This is even more baffling as localhost works fine as well but that's as expected as the token is only pointed at my domain. Does anyone a workaround for this issue and why the Trial Token even does this in the first place?